Как вывести куски кода из системной таблицы заключенные между BEGIN и END?
Как написать запрос, который выведет куски кода из системной таблицы all_source заключенный между BEGIN и END;
Простой пример :
NAME   TYPE      LINE     TEXT
....   ....      ....     ....
1233   PRIVATE   188      begin
1233   PRIVATE   189      (какой-то код)
1233   PRIVATE   190      (какой-то код)
....   ....      ....     ....
....   ....      ....     ....
1233   PRIVATE   198      end;

Так вот нужно вывести блоки кода между begin end; в одно поле
При этом таких кусков между begin end; понятное дело много
Вообще суть задачи заключается в поиске кописта кода, нужно будет потом искать совпадения по блокам, но это уже другой вопрос, пока не получается вывести сами куски, блоки кода

В общем виде, это можно сделать следующим скриптом:
DECLARE
  fullText CLOB;
  doRecord BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  FOR cur IN (
    SELECT * FROM all_source s
    WHERE s.OWNER = 'SWAD'
    AND TYPE = 'PROGER'
    AND NAME = 'ORACLE_BLOCK'
  ) LOOP
    -- Если нашли end прекращаем запись
    IF (UPPER(cur.TEXT) LIKE '%END;%') THEN
      doRecord := FALSE; -- Не записываем
      -- Это разделитель, для красоты
      fullText := fullText || ' ----------------------------------- ' || sys.utl_tcp.CRLF;
      CONTINUE; -- Ниже делать нечего, идем на следующую итерацию
    END IF;
    -- Если флаг true, пишем в переменную строку, удаляя пробелы
    IF (doRecord) THEN
      fullText := fullText || TRIM(cur.TEXT);
      CONTINUE; -- Ниже делать нечего, идем на следующую итерацию
    END IF;
    -- Если нашли бегин, записываем со следующей строки
    IF (UPPER(cur.TEXT) LIKE '%BEGIN%') THEN
      doRecord := TRUE;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
  -- Вывод в буфер, а так пишите куда хотите.
  dbms_output.put_line(fullText);
END;

Если в искомом объекте будет код с вложенными блоками, то надо будет скрипт допилить и вводить счетчик бегинов и ендов.
Но тут уже от вашей задумки зависит, т.к. не понятно, какой, допустим из 3-х вложений вам нужен.

правильно работать не будет.  хотя бы из-за отсутствия сортировки в селекте )))

@ESkri Ну вот далеко не факт. Сколько я не селектил из этой вьюхи, записи всегда выводились отсортированные по полю LINE. Эта вьюшка построена на еще одном системном представлении(int$dba_source), но вот доступа туда у меня нет, что бы увидеть, как она формируется. Если вдруг случится, что записи выводятся в другом порядке, то добавить ORDER BY труда не составит.

ты на вьюху, которая внутри себя отсортирована, повесил сверху свой фильтр, и надеешься что в получившемся селекте сортировка сохранится? )))

@ESkri Да! И она сохраняется ) Вообще оракл без причины не меняем порядок сортировки записей. Сколько раз использовал сортировку во внутренних запросах, обернутых по несколько раз и порядок не менялся. Но если "стремно" можно воткнуть ORDER BY по отсортированному

И она сохраняется, пока объём данных мал )))  Оракл этого не гарантирует, а надеяться на случайности глупо.
